# Excluding the nagios directory from Basic Auth that is set for the root directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nagios, http-basic-authentication, exclude

I have basic auth from the root directory for Apache. I am setting it like so.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/xxxx.conf

```
 <Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile xxxxxxxx
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Since this setting is set at root, it overrides the Basic Auth for Nagios rendering Nagios inoperable. I tried to exclude the Nagios directory by doing

```
  <Location /nagios>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
  </Location>
```

But that disabled authentication all together since it takes presidence against the Nagios settings.

What is the correct way of excluding just the Nagios sub-directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the "Directory" directive instead of the "Location" directive. Locations tend to have a wider scope which makes fine-grained control more difficult.

Comment: And make sure you have the correct AllowOverride AuthConfig in place to allow the subdirectory permissions to have effect.

Comment: That did it! Thanks, taking note on the Location scope vs Directory.